# What is the correct term for a fear of breasts?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I have known this is a phobia for quite a while and remember reading the word long ago, but when I googled it today I got 2 different spellings: mastophobia and mastrophobia. Which one is right? Is either a recognised word? — I couldn't find them in the Oxford dictionary. Is it one of the newly made up words and there isn’t an official word to describe the fear of breasts?

If there is such a word but it's not mastophobia or mastrophobia, what is it?

Example sentence:

> Eric liked cold cities where people wore lots of clothing. He positively avoided popular beaches in summer, due to his ______.

Comment: *Masto-* is a combining form found in OED, with two different meanings; *mastro-* is not. *Mastophobia* therefore is known to have a couple of meanings. However, even the OED is not entirely exhaustive and *mastrophobia* might have a meaning.

Comment: @choster I am thinking of a word that describes “the fear of breasts”.

Comment: “the fear of breasts” - I know what you mean; they sure are scary.

Comment: Perhaps "masto-" was erroneously changed to "mastro-" by some writers by analogy with claustrophobia, hydrophobia, acrophobia, etc

Comment: Perhaps *mammophobia*?

Comment: @jxh Or *Mammaphobia*: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mamma Ety->the Latin. Oops, this guy says we should stick with Greek, so *mastophobia* as user323578 suggests: https://mbarrick.livejournal.com/741081.html It wouldn't do to mix old languages.

Comment: I agree that we need to stick with Greek, but I'm a little phobic that a Greek expert will pounce on me, so I'll stick with comments. Starting from μαστοί, I can think of two English derivatives, mastitis (breast inflammation) and mastectomy (surgical removal of the breast). But whether the neologism should be mastiphobia or mastephobia or mastphobia? I don't know.

Comment: Latin+Greek precedents are abound, but I had *mammogram* in mind.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Why not?  Claustrophobia is exactly this!  From *claustrum*

Comment: By analogy with “sun stroke”, I suggest “ breaststroke”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't see why people are having problems combining Latin and Greek; this is common, and present in the classic *claustrophobia*.  The *claustro* comes from the Latin *claustrum* 'to close' and *phobia* is Greek.**

---

**mammophobia** is the correct term to use here.

I don't know where "mastro" came from; it doesn't appear to be an actual thing and is not listed as a combining form in the Oxford English Dictionary.

**masto-** denotes "surgical or medical procedures involving the breasts" according to the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/233584?rskey=F67GzH&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) so is the incorrect term.

The correct form, **mammo-** "denotes the mamma (breast)"

From this, we can conclude:

> **mammophobia** *noun*.  A fear or aversion to breasts.
>   
> Etymology:  **mammo** *comb. form* denoting the breasts **+** **-phobia** *comb. form* a fear or aversion to something.

[image: OED]

[OED *"mammo"*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113163?redirectedFrom=-mammo#eid)

[OED *"-phobia"*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/142572?isAdvanced=false&result=2&rskey=IeuOgt&)

Comment: I would have said "boobophobia".

Comment: So you would call a fear of cats feline-phobia by combining Latin and Greek? But im the correct term is Ailurophobia! And mastitis is not a medical procedure. Rather, an inflammation of the breast tissue.

Comment: @rajah9 Mastitis has nothing to do with the matter.  Combining Latin and Greek is common today!  *Claustrophobia*?

Comment: Not to mention *television*.